# How to get HTTP Response Code using Selenium(-Wire)

Tags: python, selenium, networking, response

is there any Way, without using a Proxy, to catch the Network Response with Selenium(-Wire)?

[image: Text]

Answer (score 1):

With selenium wire yes.

```
driver.last_request.response
```

for the last response.

You can also get the first or all responses.

```
print(driver.last_request.response)
```

Will, in your case, print "200 OK"

You can also get just the response code with:

```
driver.last_request.response.status_code
```